# Cookies are blocked in WKWebView after updating to iOS 14

Tags: ios, cookies, sharepoint, wkwebview

In our custom Sharepoint app we use https://login.microsoftonline.com/ to authenticate the user in our WKWebView. This has worked fine until iOS 14. After updating to iOS 14 https://login.microsoftonline.com/ says that the browser blocks the cookies?
[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exidq.jpg)